# How to do Latent Semantic Analysis on a very large dataset

Tags: matlab, nlp, pca, dimensionality-reduction, latent-semantic-analysis

I am trying to run LSA or Principal component analysis on a very large dataset, about 50,000 documents and over 300,000 words/terms, to reduce the dimensionality so I can graph the documents in 2-d.

I have tried in Python and in MATLAB but my system runs out of memory and crashes in either instance because of the dataset's volume.  Does anyone know how I can reduce the load, or do some sort of approximate LSA/PCA which can run quicker and more efficiently?  My overall goal is big dimensionality reduction over the 300k words.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Oja's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule). It defines an iterative procedure to learn PCA. Now you just have to implement that you don't load the whole dataset at once from disk to prevent overloading your memory.